# Overriding save method to create second auto incrementing field in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to override the save method on a model in order to generate a unique, second auto-incrementing id.

I create my class and override the save() method, but for some reason it is erroring out with the following error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Here's the code:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    target = models.OneToOneField(Target)
    person = models.OneToOneField(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    gender_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.person_id = "%07d" % self.id
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is it because I didn't pass an id parameter and it hasn't saved yet? Is there anyway to generate a value from the id?

Comment: just change the order.. call super before the assignment.

Comment: Also, it might be better to use `post_save` signal instead of overriding `save()` method.

Comment: What's the purpose of the field?

Answer (score 3):

Safest and easiest way to achieve what you want is to use a `post_save` signal because it is fired right after `save` is called, but before the transaction is committed to the database.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver    
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


@receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
def set_person_id(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     if created:
         instance.person_id = "%07d" % instance.id
         instance.save()
```

Comment: This will send the OP into recursion. Is there any particular reason to bring signals to the mix?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the check for `created`. 
@SebastianWozny because the signal is in the same transaction as the `save()` method, and is much easier to use than doing manual transaction management.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, self.id will be `None`in some cases, and then the assignment will fail.
However you cannot just the assignment and the call to `super`, as suggested in the comments, because then you wouldn't be persisting the assignment to the database layer.

You need to check whether the model has an id and then proceed differently:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id: # Upon instance creation
             super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Acquire an ID  
             self.person_id = "%07d" % self.id         # Set the person_id
        return super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This issues two save operations to the database. You will want to wrap them in a transaction to make sure your database receives these two fields simultaneously.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction
class Person(models.Model):
    target = models.OneToOneField(Target)
    person = models.OneToOneField(User)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    gender_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    def create_person_id(self):
        if not self.id: # Upon instance creation
                 super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Acquire an ID  
                 self.person_id = "%07d" % self.id         
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                self.create_person_id
                return super(Person, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise # or deal with the error
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that signals might be the better option, if not, try using pk instead of id.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # [ . . . ]
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.person_id = "%07d" % self.pk
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```